# Mysql error connecting to DB

Tags: mysql

I tried everything I saw in 50 pages of searching. I am getting really hot headed over this. I reinstalled my machine and from now on Mysql just doesn't want to connect.

```
"Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user".
```

Tried going into the ini file, SQL commands GRANT and whatever you can think of. I can't connect to the damn thing. Can someone help?

Comment: Post your connection code (leaving out user/pass). Is it a localhost or remote server?

Comment: "$DBconnection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'pesho123', 'maina123', 'test');"  It's a test project ,don't care about username/password.

Comment: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON test TO pesho123 IDENTIFIED BY 'maina123';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
I had the same problem before re-installing my OS.This SQL fixed it then.Now it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try the root user and see if that works.

Comment: It works for root but it doesn't work for the user i created.I changed it from every possible location including config.inc.php.

Comment: Do you have access to phpmyadmin or another graphical mysql tool? If not, you can do this to see if the user is in the database: SELECT * FROM mysql.user; Make sure the user is added to localhost and % so it can connect.

Comment: Yes i have access to phpmyadmin.I give privileges to the user from all possible places ,still can't connect with it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new user using this code:

```
GRANT SELECT ON test.* TO pesho124@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'maina123';
```

and see if that works.

Comment: Yes it works but it's strange why i can't connect with a user i created before with global privileges.

Comment: I think its because you didn't add the 'localhost', well at least not in the connection code you provided. You either need 'localhost' or a wildcard so it knows which host you can connect to. You should be able to delete the other user and re-add it using the GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES. Please up-vote my answer. Thanks :)